# How to embed an interactive chart generated with rCharts into a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: r, embed, powerpoint, interactive, rcharts

I have seen recently very nice interactive charts created with the [rCharts](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts)  package. And now my question is:

It's possible to embed these graphs with full functionality into a PowerPoint presentation?

some directions to start with this example:?

```
require(devtools)
install_github('ramnathv/rCharts')

require(rCharts)
names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))

hair_eye_male <- subset(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), Sex == "Male")
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = "Eye", data = hair_eye_male, 
  type = 'multiBarChart')
n1
```

Comment: http://www.mango-solutions.com/wp/2015/02/embedding-r-generated-interactive-html-pages-in-ms-powerpoint/

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried this plug-in but doesn't works with the above example. This show me an empty box.

Answer (score 0):

There is an active x control called Microsoft Web Browser (which can be found in the developer tab). The plugin in hrbrmstr's [link](http://www.mango-solutions.com/wp/2015/02/embedding-r-generated-interactive-html-pages-in-ms-powerpoint/) is maybe based on it.

PowerPoint won't allow to insert a web page in both cases because this active x control is disabled for security reasons. There is a [workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2793374) (I have not tested it)